# Pass expression as variable to curve

Tags: r

I am trying to use a variable that stores a function name as a character string to draw a curve. Something like the following:

```
f1 <- function(x) 0*x
f2 <- function(x) 1 + 0*x
f3 <- function(x) 2 + 0*x

fn <- "f1"

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 3))

curve(get(fn), add = TRUE)
Error in curve(get(fn), add = TRUE) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'

curve(f1, add = TRUE)
curve(f2, add = TRUE)
curve(f3, add = TRUE)
```

I know I am missing something with how `curve` handles the expressions with substitute, or how `get` is passing the function. I am particularly confused because `class(get(fn))` returns "function".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the issue is that `curve()` doesn't evaluate the parameter you pass in. It looks at what you passed in to the parameter, not the results of evaluating the parameter. When you run

```
curve(fn)
```

what you're passing in is a "name" (or "symbol"). That triggers the function to find the function with that name. When you run

```
curve(get("f1"))  #error
```

you've passed in a call. Again, that call isn't executed by curve to see that it returns a function. As the error message says, if you pass in a call, that expression should contain `x`. For example

```
curve(f1(x))
```

is an example of the call syntax with the `x` variable.

If you really need to specify the function as a character vector, you can convert the character to a name object and then build the call to curve with do.call. For example

```
do.call("curve",list(as.name(fn)))
```

or you can modify your call to trigger the resulting function with the special `x` variable

```
curve(get(fn)(x))
```

Comment: And if you wanted to add extra arguments, such as `add = TRUE`, it would look like this: `do.call(curve, list(as.name(fn), add = TRUE))`

Comment: You can also skirt the issue by first forcing the evaluation `{get(fn)->f;curve(f,add=TRUE)}`